# Non-abelian groups with trivial socle.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, infinite-groups, socle

Recently, my teacher told me about Socle of a group $G$. So, I know that the socle $Soc(G)$ of a group $G$ is the subgroup generated by all minimal normal subgroups of $G$. I was thinking then that the socle of a simple group $S$ is the group $S$ itself. What I can't find is that examples of non-abelian groups with trivial socle. After thinking a bit, I get that such a non-abelian group $G$ with trivial socle must be infinite. Also, for every normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ there exists an infinite chain of normal subgroups of $G$ inside $N$.

Can you please tell me some examples of non-abelian groups with trivial socle?

Comment: See this [MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96659/infinite-p-groups-with-no-normal-subgroups).

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't understand the reference that you mentioned. Can you please give me some example of a non-abelian non-simple group with trivial socle?

Comment: [McLain's group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/McLain%27s_group) is a non-abelian group with trivial socle.

Comment: What about free groups?

Comment: I am not able to show that free groups do not possess minimal normal subgroups, whereas I can see that free groups do have normal subgroups.

Comment: I'm not sure of the relevance of the "non-abelian" assumption. The group $\mathbf{Z}$ is an obvious example with trivial socle (as is any torsion-free abelian group). A very close non-abelian example is the infinite dihedral group.

Comment: Also, torsion-free residually finite groups have trivial socle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nonabelian free groups are examples. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a nonabelian free group $F$. Then $N$ is free, so $N$ has proper characteristic subgroups, for example $[N,N]$ if $N$ is nonabelian and $N^2$ if $N$ is abelian (although in fact there are no nontrivial cyclic normal subgroups), so $N$ is not a minimal normal subgroup of $F$.